# Why Select method of linq to EF sorting the output list?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have Shifts table in SQL Server db

```
RecID   ShiftTime   StartTime   EndTime
1       Day         06:40       15:45
2       After       15:46       23:30
3       Night       23:31       06:39
4       ShortDay    06:40       12:30
5       MiddDay     12:31       19:00
```

RecID - int, ShiftTime, StartTime and EndTime - varchar(20)

When I evaluate following linq query
`var shiftsNames = context.Shifts.Select(s => s.ShiftTime);`
it is sorts the output as After, Day, MiddDay, Night, ShortDay.

In this form
`var shifts = context.Shifts.ToList();`
`var shiftsNames = shifts.Select(s=>s.ShiftTime).ToList();`
linq works as expected without sorting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first query returns the sorting from SQL server - which is not specified in the query, so you cannot assume anything about the order.
Same goes for the second query, but there the default "unsorted" order seems to work.
Add sorting if you need it.

Try this in SQL:

```
Select * from table
Select col from table
```

Which will most probably get different sort order. This is what you see here.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. Indeed **SELECT shiftTime
FROM Shift** returns sorted data.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ doesn't sort rows, if `order by` clause or `OrderBy` function are not defined. The reason of selecting rows in different order is a standard SQL behavior. Without `order by` clause, the rows  returned in an unpredictable way. Often, this the order of the physically rows in the database, but not necessarily. If there are one or more indexes defined for the database, the order will depend on the index(es) used.

Check [this aticle](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/05/20/without-order-by-there-is-no-default-sort-order.aspx) with examples.